# The check for zero and null not working properly in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, logical-operators

I have a dataset that has a column `std` which contains 0 and null values.
I want to filter them out, so I use the OR condition :

```
df.filter((col('std')!=0) | col('std').isNotNull())
```

However i am getting `std` values that are 0.
But if I use the AND condition, it works. 
How is this possible?

Comment: it is expected behaviour , when you execute `!=0` all rows which are `not 0` returns `True` , when you execute a `isNotNull` all rows which are `not null` (*doesnot effect rows with 0*) is returned `True`. when you chain an OR operator , it returns whatever is true hence 0 is returned as well

Comment: 0 is a non null value. So when you use OR condition, the results will have 0 value since they satisfy the .isNotNull() condition. Eg: let's say the value is 0 now OR condition will be False for !=0, but it is true for isNotNull() so the value is returned since OR returns the value if atleast one value is true. Incase of AND both conditions should be satisfied. One more alternative is chaining the filter confitions which will do the first filter out the non null values then apply the other condition  df.filter(col('std').isNotNull()).filter(col('std')!=0)